# Is it possible for a bred Pokemon to obtain a hidden ability upon leveling up if it's female parent possessed that hidden ability?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am currently trying to get an Exploud with Scrappy in Pokemon Y, but the only way to obtain a Exploud (besides trading) is through evolving Whismur. According to Bulbapedia, Whismur cannot have the hidden ability Scrappy, so what if I were to breed a male Whismur with a female Pancham with Scrappy? Would the hatched Whismur be able to acquire Scrappy upon evolving into Loudred?

If this is not possible, would anyone happen to know of a way to acquire an Exploud with Scrappy outside of trading?

Answer (score 1):

If you breed or catch a Whismur with the ability Rattled, it will gain the ability Scrappy when it evolves into a Exploud. The only other option would be getting lucky and finding one at a friend's Safari Zone.